# Anonymous enum in Rust

Tags: rust

I use this data structure in a project:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Field {
    last_name(String),
    first_name(String),
    /* etc. */
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Update {
    pub id: Id,
    pub field: Field,
}
```

The enum is not really useful by itself, I use it for deserialization of JSON. So is it possible to do something like that?

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct PersonUpdate {
    pub id: Id,
    pub field: enum {
        last_name(String),
        first_name(String),
    }
}
```

Comment: There's some recent discussion on the internals forum: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-anonymous-enum/4806

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not possible, you must give it a name, like you did in the first example.